# Propagate function error from parent component to child component in React while making API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch

I have a common `post request function` where I am fetching  data and returning the data to the calling function. And this function is being passed on to other component as prop.

Now If I get an error while fetching the data I want to send the same err to the final `component redux` so that i can show the error in that component accordingly.

```
export const post = async (url, payload) => {
  const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res.json()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    })
  return data
}
```

Here `ParentFunction` is present in parent component and this is being passed as prop to child component.

```
function ParentFunction(url, payload) {
  postRequest(url, payload).then()
    .catch()
}
```

and passing this function reference as:

`<ChildComponent fetch={this.fun1} />`

This is the function in my child component redux where currently I am getting the data as long as I am not getting the error from post request

```
function fun2() {
  this.props.fetch.then(data => dispatch(....))
  // doing something with this data 
}
```

Now If I get an error from post request I am passing the same from parent to this function but this `fun2` throws an error saying `fun1.then`is not a function. So how am I supposed the catch the error here also.
I tried with `fun1.then().catch()` but it is not working.

Is there any way that I can achieve this ??

TL;DR:

How do I wrap fetch call in Promise so that I can use .catch when it throws error ?

Comment: Did you try to return the error and not throw it?

Comment: but if i return the err then how will I differentiate between data and err. 
Probably I maybe with extra property in the object yes that will work, but i was looking for passing the error itself

Comment: Instead of passing the function to each of the components as a prop, have an action that will trigger the ajax call and updates the data into the redux state. Using the values from the redux state you can update your components.

Comment: I would have definitely done that but this child component is another node module and it has its own redux state so thats why I was passing all there parent functions as ref to this node module

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain to you the error you are getting.

You're using async/await which returns you the result (not a promise) and when there is an exception, it throws.

Since it is not a promise, it doesn't give you `.then` or `.catch` to work with.

One way to achieve what you're trying to do is, call the function, wrap the call between `try/catch` block and you're good to go. You'll get the data as a result of the function call or you'll get the error in the catch block. Based on that you can handle how you want to pass them to props.

Sample example:

```
export const post = async (url, payload) => {
  const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res.json()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    })
  return data
}
```

Now while calling it:

```
let data = null;
let error = null;
try {
  data = post(url, payload)
} catch (e) {
  error = e;
}
```

Another way would be to return an array as a result. A basic structure could be `[err, data]`. If you successfully get the data, return `[null, data]`. If you get an exception, return `[err]`.

Sample example:

```
export const post = async (url, payload) => {
  const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers
  })
    .then(res => {
      return [null, res.json()]
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return [err]
    })

  return data
}
```

Or, you can simply use promises where you can use the usual `.then` and `.catch` that you are trying already.

Here is sample example for this:

```
export const post = (url, payload) => {
      return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers
      })
        .then(res => {
          return res.json()
        }) // as you will be catching the exception later, we can exclude catch from here...
    }
```

Here is how you call it:

```
post(url, payload)
  .then((data) => {
    // handle data
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error
  })
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, could you please explain how can I use promises or wrap this function in promises so that I can use `.catch()`

Comment: Or a better way to rephrase how do I wrap fetch in promise

Comment: Fetch already returns a promise, just to make it clear. That is the reason you were able to use `.then` and `.catch` inside your post method.

Comment: yes, but after catching it I need to catch the same in parent function and pass it on similarly to child function where also I can do `.catch()`. But yes I got your point

Comment: Yes, you can further use it as per your requirement :)

Comment: I achieved it by returning `Promise.reject(Error(err))` from the parent function. Thanks